# Connection closed before full header was received http post in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dio

I'm having problems trying to consume my API, and after following up on this problem I'm stuck in the matter and I've tried different emulators in various versions and the problem persists.

Error:

```
DioError [DioErrorType.other]: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://10.0.2.2:7108/Users/authenticate
```

Flutter doctor

[image]

Http Post

```
class AuthenticateRemoteApi extends AuthenticateGateway {
  final AuthenticateMapper _authenticateMapper = AuthenticateMapper();

  @override
  Future<SesionUser> login(Authenticate user) async {
    var dio = Dio();
    dio.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:7108/Users/authenticate';

    try {
      Response response = await dio.post(url, data: authenticateModelToJson(user));
      return _authenticateMapper.fromMap(jsonDecode(response.data));
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share more information about the  code? I think you're closing your connection without wait the response.

Comment: Yes, I already edited my question. @EduardoYamauchi

Comment: Test with `Postman` or another tool first just to be sure the Api is ok and then try to use another package like `http` to see if it works. If not then there should be a mistake with the request in your code.

Comment: The api is fine I can consume it from postman without problems @BélindaG.Freitas

Answer (score 6):

I have came with this work around by creating this interceptor.

The idea of it is when encountering this random error just to retry the request.

```
/// Interceptor
class RetryOnConnectionChangeInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  final Dio dio;

  RetryOnConnectionChangeInterceptor({
    required this.dio,
  });

  @override
  void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
  if (_shouldRetryOnHttpException(err)) {
      try {
        handler.resolve(await DioHttpRequestRetrier(dio: dio).requestRetry(err.requestOptions).catchError((e) {
          handler.next(err);
        }));
      } catch (e) {
        handler.next(err);
      }
    } else {
      handler.next(err);
    }

  }

  bool _shouldRetryOnHttpException(DioError err) {
    return err.type == DioErrorType.other &&
        ((err.error is HttpException && err.message.contains('Connection closed before full header was received')));
  }
}

/// Retrier
class DioHttpRequestRetrier {
  final Dio dio;

  DioHttpRequestRetrier({
    required this.dio,
  });

  Future<Response> requestRetry(RequestOptions requestOptions) async {
    return dio.request(
      requestOptions.path,
      cancelToken: requestOptions.cancelToken,
      data: requestOptions.data,
      onReceiveProgress: requestOptions.onReceiveProgress,
      onSendProgress: requestOptions.onSendProgress,
      queryParameters: requestOptions.queryParameters,
      options: Options(
        contentType: requestOptions.contentType,
        headers: requestOptions.headers,
        sendTimeout: requestOptions.sendTimeout,
        receiveTimeout: requestOptions.receiveTimeout,
        extra: requestOptions.extra,
        followRedirects: requestOptions.followRedirects,
        listFormat: requestOptions.listFormat,
        maxRedirects: requestOptions.maxRedirects,
        method: requestOptions.method,
        receiveDataWhenStatusError: requestOptions.receiveDataWhenStatusError,
        requestEncoder: requestOptions.requestEncoder,
        responseDecoder: requestOptions.responseDecoder,
        responseType: requestOptions.responseType,
        validateStatus: requestOptions.validateStatus,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Usage: add this interceptor [RetryOnConnectionChangeInterceptor] to your Dio client instance

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a package bug, usually appears when the user doesn't has internet connect. Reported in [#1269](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/1269) and [#377](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/377) issue from the package repository. I recommend you to use another package.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error always occurs when I build app on emulator, rarely appears on real device. If you are using Android Studio, try with Pixel 6 API 33.